# ManagementObjectSearcher causes re-entrancy issues for onclick handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am having an odd problem with protecting a section of code.  My application is a tray app.  I create a NotifyIcon inside my class (ApplicationContext).  I have assigned a balloon click handler and a double click handler to the NotifyIcon object.  there is also a context menu but I am not showing all code.  Only important pieces.

```
 public class SysTrayApplicationContext: ApplicationContext
 {
    private NotifyIcon notifyIcon;
    private MainForm afDashBoardForm;

   public SysTrayApplicationContext()
   {
    this.notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    this.notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += notifyIcon_BalloonTipClicked;
    this.notifyIcon.MouseDoubleClick += notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick;
     // ... more code
   }
```

Both handlers launch or create/show my form:

```
        private void notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
       {
          if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
          {
              openDashboard();
          }
       }

    private void notifyIcon_BalloonTipClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openDashboard();
    }

    private void openDashboard()
    {
            if (dashBoardForm != null)
            {
                log.Debug("Dashboard form created already, so Activate it");
                dashBoardForm.Activate();
            }
            else
            {
                log.Debug("Dashboard form does not exist, create it");
                dashBoardForm = new MainForm();
                dashBoardForm.Show();
            }
    }
```

There is a problem with the above code.  Maybe more than 1.  Issue: it is possible to display 2 dashboard forms which is not what I want.  If user double clicks on tray icon while balloon message is displaying causes a race condition in openDashboard.  I can reproduce this easily.  So I added a lock around the code in openDashboard code and, to my surprise, that did NOT prevent 2 dashboard forms from displaying.  I should not be able to create 2 MainForms.  Where am I going wrong here?

here is the updated code with lock statement:

```
        private void openDashboard()
        {
          lock (dashBoardFormlocker)
          {
            if (dashBoardForm != null)
            {
                log.Debug("Dashboard form created already, so Activate it");
                dashBoardForm.Activate();
            }
            else
            {
                log.Debug("Dashboard form does not exist, create it");
                dashBoardForm = new MainForm();
                dashBoardForm.Show();
            }
         }
      }
```

Note: lock object was added to the class and initialized in constructor.

```
private object dashBoardFormlocker;
```

UPDATE:  Showing more code.  this is how code gets started :

```
    static void Main()
    {
        if (SingleInstance.Start())
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            // For a system tray application we don't want to create 
            // a form, we instead create a new ApplicationContext.  The Run method takes
            Application.Run(new SysTrayApplicationContext());
            SingleInstance.Stop();
            SingleInstance.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2: Provide more code for clarity

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{

    public MainForm()
    {
        log.Trace("MainForm constructor...");
        InitializeComponent();
        // ... code not shown
        this.label_OSVersion.Text = getOSFriendlyName();

        // .. more code
    }

    private string getOSFriendlyName()
    {
        try
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            var mgmtObj = (from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get().OfType<ManagementObject>()
                           select x.GetPropertyValue("Caption")).FirstOrDefault();
            result = mgmtObj != null ? mgmtObj.ToString() : string.Empty;
            OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion; 
            String sp = os.ServicePack ?? string.Empty;

            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result) ? result + sp : "Unknown";
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error trying to get the OS version", ex);
            return "Unknown";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are the multiple threads in this? Forms (and almost all standard Windows UI components) share a single thread so `lock` won't work as you are expecting.

Comment: I thought balloon click would operate on a different thread.

Comment: Why would it? It posts a `WM_CLICK` (or whatever) to the message queue within the messaging/windowing system. The message pump picks it up and fires off the appropriate event.

Comment: Also, is NotifyIcon considered a standard UI component?  There is no main form for this application.  Form is new'd up later.

Comment: Yes. It still works on the same basic messaging/windowing system.

Comment: Also note that only the UI thread can modify UI controls. Unless you start a explicitly start a thread or asynchronous operation, you can assume that all your code runs in the UI thread

Comment: OK, I will assume you are correct.  I can remove locking logic.  However, I still have a very weird problem that "looks" like a race condition.  In my log I see the message "Dashboard form does not exist, create it" 2 times in a row.  This should not happen.  I am not understanding how dashboardForm != null can be null for multiple checks if they are on a single thread.

Comment: If you only want to display one instance of your form then shouldn't you have a static reference to it? `private static MainForm afDashBoardForm;`

Comment: @Equalsk, litterally just beat me to it, was about to echo the same point, the locker should be a static object and not part of the class instance:          `private static readonly object afDashBoardForm= new object();`

Comment: @Equalsk, reasonable suggestion but null check with a single threaded app should work.  In my case, since I see 2 forms launched, only one will be assigned to the dashboardForm object.  The other would be orphaned I would guess.

Comment: @DubMan, I did try locker as static and the behavior did not change.

Comment: Are you sure that it is a race condition? I suspect its more likely you are logging to the same file twice.

Comment: Comments about single threadedness are valid.  On a single thread, I am seeing the code execute the "if (dashBoardForm != null)"
check inside openDashboard 2 times.  Once for the double click event and once for the balloon click event.  I expect this.  However, both checks oddly return false.  This means the before the dashboardForm is created and assigned the second null check runs and also returns null.  I would have thought the first event would complete before the 2nd event would start.  Eventhough this is not a multi-threaded issue, it seems one handler is paused while another runs.

Comment: Are you sure it's `dashboardForm` and not `afDashBoardForm`? Seems there's an inconsistency there?

Comment: @Lloyd, sorry, that's a typo and fixed now.

Comment: When you enter `openDashboard()` before any other statement, are you sure the main form is null? You don't create it anywhere else?

Comment: @Lloyd, First question:  Logging seems with indicate main form is null when first event fired (which always seems to be the balloon click event).  2nd Question: Yes, openDashboard is the single point of entry.  Both events are tied to this for code simplicity.

Comment: Also note, I have taken steps to assure that only 1 tray app exists.  It is a well know technique, and no need to post code.  Uses a mutex.

Comment: Typically, forms are start with Application.run (new form()).  In my case, I am newing a form and then doing show().  I wonder if this is an issue?  The behavior of the form seems fine.

Comment: All that passing a `Form` to `Application.Run()` does is have the `Run()` method show that form, and use that form to decide when to exit the process. Otherwise, everything works the same. I agree with other comments that everything _should_ be in one thread, so no thread-race-condition exists here. But without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's unlikely you'll get an answer.

Comment: OK, I've run this one down.  I thought perhaps it had something to do with the creation of the dashboard form.  So, I started focusing there.  In the constructor of my dashBoardForm I am doing this: searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem") to retrieve the "friendly" OS version.  When I run searcher.Get() I'm getting some unexpected behavior that allows a single thread to run 2 different events and allow the condition "if (dashBoardForm != null)" to be false for both.

Comment: When this code is removed all works fine.  Interestly, if I replace offending code with something like Thread.sleep(2000) all still works fine.  It is definitely the ManagementObjectSearcher but I can't tell you why.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I tried to post as much code as seems pertinent. but of course, it is not complete.  There is much other "noise" going on i could not post.  I've said a couple of times here that responders were correct about this not being a multi-threaded issue, but it sure looked the part.  I am well aware of the fact that Winform apps run on a single UI thread however I did not consider this tray application is that class.  Also, I doubt that anyone would have gotten the answer even if I posted all code.  This is just weird to me.

Comment: I guarantee that with a **good** code example, someone can provide an answer. Please read the link I provided above for details on what such a code example is. It is your obligation to _remove_ the noise, and provide not all of your code, but the _minimum_ amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. I find it especially ironic that you know at this point that the class `ManagementObjectSearcher` is somehow involved, but your use of it isn't included in the code you posted.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I do get what your saying, still its quite a bit of code to post when your not exactly sure where to look or what to pull out.  I did in fact create another project with everything stripped out and it worked perfectly (no point in posting that).  So, somewhere in between that stripped version and my production version is the problem.  I guess I could have added one line of code at a time into the stripped version and found the answer without posting.  But then we wouldn't have any of this interesting content, which I do find helpful and interesting.  I need to change the title.

Comment: _"I guess I could have added one line of code at a time into the stripped version and found the answer without posting"_ -- yes, that is a common outcome when someone actually works to present their question well. It's one of the most important reasons to do that! _"then we wouldn't have any of this interesting content"_ -- I don't see any interesting content, just a bunch of guessing and stating of the well-known (if not obvious). All of this "content" is available elsewhere in a much more easily-digested form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main UI thread must always pump a message loop to support communication from COM components.
So when you do a blocking operation from the UI thread like locking or joining a thread, (EDIT: edited based on Peter Duniho's fix) the UI thread will enter an 'alertable' state, allowing COM to dispatch certain type of messages, which in turn can cause re-entrancy issues like in your scenario.
Look at the answer to this question ([Why did entering a lock on a UI thread trigger an OnPaint event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431221/why-did-entering-a-lock-on-a-ui-thread-trigger-an-onpaint-event)) for a much more accurate explanation.

Looking at the source code of `ManagementObjectSearcher.Get` there is a lock (inside `Initialize`), and since you call it from the constructor of your form, it may lead to the second event triggering while the form's constructor has not finished. The assignment to the `dashBoardFormlocker` variable only happens after the constructor finishes, so that would explain why it was null on the second entry.

The moral of the story is never do blocking operations on the UI thread.

Comment: Good information about ManagementObjectSearcher.  Are you saying the lock inside the Initialize method is causing the first event handler to be preempted by the second event?  I didn't think this could happen with a single UI thread.  I am for sure expecting to see both events fire.  I am not expecting to see one event handler stop before it completes allowing another event run "alternating-style".

Comment: Note: I did remove all locking code on my side.  The issue did not stop.  It does appear to be completely tied to ManagementObjectSearcher.Get().

Comment: _"So when you do a blocking operation from the UI thread like locking or joining a thread the CLR will knowingly wait for incoming events"_ -- this is IMHO misleading. What actually happens is that as a side-effect of a thread entering an "alertable" state, it is possible for COM to get involved and dispatch certain messages, which in turn can result in the re-entrant mouse message. This is really more of a WIndows thing than something that the CLR does specifically to try to avoid deadlock (indeed, GUI thread deadlock is a very real and unavoidable problem for incorrectly written code).

Comment: @Jim: _"Are you saying the lock inside the Initialize method is causing the first event handler to be preempted by the second event"_ -- this is what's being said, and it's entirely plausible. Just set a breakpoint in the debugger and look at the stack trace when the second mouse event comes in. You'll likely see a call to `Monitor.Enter()` just before `NativeWindow.Callback()` and the subsequent handling of the second mouse message. The event handling isn't "alternating", it's re-entrant; i.e. handling of the first event is interrupted and not resumed until handling of the second is done.

Comment: @Peter Duniho: thanks for your fix, I was basing that sentence on Hans Passant's answer on the question I linked to, speficially this quote: "The CLR is very much aware of that requirement and does something about it." Perhaps I misunderstood. I edited the answer based on your explanation.

Comment: @PeterDuniho and tzachs, some very good insite here guys.  I did learn something from this.  I accepted tzachs answer simply because it was posted first and provided a plausible answer as to why the ManagementObjectSearcher get() operation was causing my issues.  Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what the problem is. But [the guess by answerer tzachs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31253624) seems reasonable. If so, you can fix your problem by changing your method to look like this:

```
private bool _dashboardOpen;

private void openDashboard()
{
    if (_dashboardOpen)
    {
        if (dashBoardForm != null)
        {
            log.Debug("Dashboard form created already, so Activate it");
            dashBoardForm.Activate();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        log.Debug("Dashboard form does not exist, create it");
        _dashboardOpen = true;
        dashBoardForm = new MainForm();
        dashBoardForm.Show();
    }
}
```

In that way, any re-entrant attempt to open the window will be detected. Note that you still need the check for `null` before actually activating; you can't activate a window that hasn't actually finished being created yet. The subsequent call to `Show()` will take care of activation anyway, so ignoring the activation in the re-entrant case shouldn't matter.

Comment: This did work in the context of my app.  When the 2nd event comes through it is effectively ignored due to _dashboardOpen== true and dashBoardForm == null.  This is perfectly fine.