# When does WaitOne execute non-framework code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I experience race conditions leading to other code being executed during a call to `System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne`, on the thread `WaitOne` is running on. From its documentation, I assumed that `WaitOne` blocks the thread for any non-framework code until one of its return conditions is met.

**In what situations, if any, is `WaitOne` supposed to execute non-framework code before returning?**

---

Sadly, I cannot determinate what method has been used to schedule the code that actually is executed in my case. However, I can still give some details:

- An application outside of my control (Outlook) loads an unmanaged DLL, which calls a managed DLL, which calls a method on a WCF proxy. WCF's implementation calls `WaitOne`, during which call the issue occurs. This means that there are several unmanaged/managed transitions on the stack.
- The WCF connection goes through a `NetNamedPipeBinding`, the target process has previously been started from the managed DLL.
- During the WCF proxy invocation, Outlook gets a chance to execute code on the same thread. After that code execution, the invocation still finishes correctly.
- I only observed this behavior on the main/ui thread
- I only observed this behavior in 32 bit builds. 64 bit builds work as expected.
- When moving all WCF calls to a different thread, and switching to explicit invocations of `Task.Wait` (on tasks created via `Task.Run`), the `Wait` presents the same behavior; it is thus likely that `Monitor.Wait` and other related methods behave in an equal way.

Comment: Probably here is your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431221/why-did-entering-a-lock-on-a-ui-thread-trigger-an-onpaint-event

Comment: @Timmy_A: thanks for the link! Definitively a hot candidate, although I don't (yet) understand why these calls only happen on 32 bit.

Comment: @Timmy_A: seems that APCs are indeed the cause. Feel free to add a suitable quote to your comment and re-post it as answer, I'll then delete my quote-only answer and accept yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All waits in .NET are "alertable." This means that if a wait blocks, Windows can run "Asynchronous Procedure Calls" on top of the waiting stack.
>
> <sub>– [Nicholas Butler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115098/nicholas-butler), excerpt from [an answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8431685/2636001) linked by [Timmy_A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3599970/timmy-a) in the comments</sub>